# Sort HOA by key first, then value

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I've got a HoA that I'm setting up as follows (test example):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @array1 = qw (1 1 1 4 5); # Note '1' appears several times
my @array2 = qw (a b c d e);
my @array3 = qw (8 6 7 9 10);
my @array4 = qw (f g h i j);


my %hash;   
push @{$hash{$array1[$_]}}, [ $array2[$_], $array3[$_], $array4[$_] ] for 0 .. $#array1;

for my $key (sort keys %hash) { 
    for my $array (@ { $hash{$key} } ) {
        my ($array2, $array3, $array4) = @$array;
        print "[$key] $array2\t$array3\t$array4\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1] a   8   f
[1] b   6   g
[1] c   7   h
[4] d   9   i
[5] e   10  j
```

What I want to do is be able to sort by the key first (as above) but in the instances where the key is the same, sort on a different array contained in the hash - e.g. numerically by the values in `@array3`, to give the desired output:

```
        *
[1] b   6   g
[1] c   7   h
[1] a   8   f
[4] d   9   i
[5] e   10  j
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace this line

```
for my $array (@ { $hash{$key} } ) {
```

by

```
for my $array ( sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @{ $hash{$key} } ) {
```

All the arrayrefs in `@{ $hash{$key} }` have the element you want to sort on at index 1. This sort block orders them in numerically ascending order by the second field.